# How to replace all values in a field (column) in table in Teradata based on a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, teradata

Say I have a particular table with 2 fields titled COLOUR and VALUE. I would like to change all values in the COLOUR field where the value=2 from BLUE to ORANGE, but just the values where VALUE=2.

The current query I am working with is simple:

```
REPLACE COLOUR('BLUE','ORANGE')
FROM TABLE1
WHERE VALUE=2;
```

This query isnt working. I know this is a super simple problem but does anyone know what kind of query I would need to solve this? Teradata documentation is not any help right now.

Thank you!

Comment: Change - like replacing in a SELECT's result, or UDPATE table data (on disk)?

Comment: So my new query would be UPDATE COLOUR('BLUE','ORANGE')
FROM TABLE1
WHERE VALUE=2; ?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET COLOUR = 'ORANGE'
WHERE VALUE = 2 AND COLOUR = 'BLUE'
```